# How secure is Laravel 4 Auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel and I noticed that it has an auth library but I would like to know what threats does it protect against. For example, does it use any technique to protect against brute force attacks?

Comment: You better ask on Laravel forums.

Comment: from what I'm seeing no, it doesn't protect against brute force attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel `Auth` library/class only autheticate the user (or whatever you may authenticate) in your system and using it with the filters, you can garantee that the user only see what is permited for him to see. It does not really care in secure your system against attacks, for exemple. That's is on you!